# Late 90's or early 00's graphic novel with a girl and an airship

Tags: story-identification, novel

I'm trying to remember the name of a graphic novel from the late 90's or early 00's. I've done a bunch of searching online but can't find anything. I don't have much to go off of. It was beautifully drawn series of comics or compiled into a graphic novel.

1. It was mostly if not only B/W and a serial comic that were collected into several books.
2. Each book was some grand adventure in a new place (maybe) one of which was on a ship, or air ship, or balloon ship.
3. The central character was this young girl who is looking for her parents or her parents died or something. She has tube like hair and giant eyes. She has been thrown into this fantasy world and is exploring/looking running from... haha. I think she has a crew of weird creature friends that are helping her. There's all these strange creatures, big and small and strange and beautiful landscapes. More on the girl: She looked a little like [Popeye's wife](https://www.google.com/search?q=olive%20oyl&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi019-Am9zUAhVKeD4KHRR4BHkQ_AUIBigB&biw=1274&bih=655) and she acted young and would get angry a lot. The drawings were ornate and detailed, but who wouldn't be if you were thrown into a fantasy world.
4. The drawing style was almost like the style of Bone, or the Arrival.

It was so long ago, and I have this vivid memory of reading it, but I've even gone back to search through all the graphic novels at my old library where it was and it's not there... ha. I wonder if it was like a small publishing company or something.

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Probably not [La Route d'Armilia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_route_d%27Armilia).

Comment: Wonderful thanks for the guide :-)

Comment: Unfortunately not, David. But thx!

Comment: Do you remember the language (and if it was the original language)? Maybe some names (or how they sounded like)?

Comment: Could you add links to "Bone" and "the Arrival", I've found multiple stories of that name.

Comment: Small Girl, Strange Creatures, Black/White. Could be Isabelle http://www.2dgalleries.com/planches/2015/206/will-1975-isabelle-et-les-malefices-de-l-oncle-hermes-2mnd.jpg

Comment: Wow. I did not expect this question to garner so much interest. Bare with me everyone :-) haha.

Comment: It was in english when I read it. I think there were some alien languages, but it was so long ago. It isn't Isabelle but that looks like a great comic book series as well! Regardless on whether or not we figure out this thing or not, it's provided a lot of interesting new texts to look into!

Comment: Link to Arrival: https://www.amazon.com/Arrival-Shaun-Tan/dp/0439895294

Comment: Link to Bone:http://www.boneville.com/

Comment: The tube hair makes me think of Akiko on the Planet Smoo by Mark Crilley..

Comment: Hold mother of god! Mkennedy! That's it! I can't believe you found it! Submit an answer so I can say you solved it! :-)

Comment: Wow. The memory as a kid in junior high reading this is vastly different experience than reading it now :-\

Comment: Done! It's pretty barebones though as I'm on my phone.

Comment: What is "tube-like hair"?

Comment: @MissMonicaE See the image in the accepted answer. Tube = cylindrical.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The tube hair gave it away.

[Akiko](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Akiko_(comic_book)) is an independent, black-and-white comic by Mark Crilley. It was first published in the mid-1990s.

Akiko is a Japanese-American girl who ends up in another planet. In the first storyline, Akiko on the Planet Smoo, she and several companions are trying to find the son of the King. The companions include Spuckler, a mechanic adventurer, heart-of-gold kinda guy, Mr Beeba, a older scientist, a robot--Gax, and a alien, Poog.

The stories can be enjoyed by kids and adults. There is some danger, but not as extreme as say, Bone, or a usual superhero comic book.

As you can see below, Akiko has her hair in pigtails which are cylindrical rather than coming to a point like usual pigtails.

[image: Cover of the first graphic novel, Akiko on the Planet Smoo]

Comment: Can you add details into your answer. e.g. does it have a airship or air balloon?

Comment: I don't remember. Based on the first issue's cover, it was like a flying car. The OP could be remembering a later story,  perhaps one that I haven't read.

Comment: I'll try to add in character names etc later today.

Answer (score 27):

You may be looking for Girl Genius, [webcomic link](http://www.girlgeniusonline.com/).
Started out as a print comic then switched online early 2000's. It's the adventures of Lady Agatha Heterodyne, done in the style of ***gaslamp*** fantasy. Beautifully drawn with a mix of black and white and color, has airships and a bunch of adventures. Currently with 16 volumes collected in graphic novels.

[image: SCIENCE!]

[image: Airships]

Comment: There are also non-graphical novels, like [Agatha Heterodyne And The Airship City](https://www.bookdepository.com/Agath-H-and-the-Airship-City-Phil-Foglio-Kaj-Foglio/9781597802116).

Comment: Quick question: is the pre-online content also available online, or only as a print comic?

Comment: @Nzall The whole story is available online. (Excluding the novels and radio plays, I think.) The early pages used to be black and white, but were later coloured.

Comment: Hey Ken, Thanks for the comment. It's not Girl Genius, but that looks like an awesome comic.

Comment: Its still going btw. New comic posted online MW&F last I checked. And yes, @carlelsaesser, it is awesome.

Comment: Even though this isn't the comic the OP was looking for, I ended up really liking it myself. Thanks for the suggestion, Ken.

Answer (score 5):

Is it [Aeon Flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86on_Flux_(film))?

> In 2011, a deadly pathogenic virus has killed 99% of the Earth's
>   population, forcing the survivors to regroup and scatter across the
>   Earth.
>
> 404 years later, in late 2415, all of the survivors inhabit Bregna, a
>   walled futuristic city-state, which is ruled by a congress of
>   scientists. Although Bregna is largely an idyllic place in the
>   destroyed Earth, people routinely disappear and the population suffers
>   from nightmares.
>
> ...
>
> She convinces the other Monicans to ignore the Handler and to help her
>   kill Oren and his men. Æon goes to destroy the Relical, the
>   **dirigible** that stores the DNA for cloning.

The movie came before the comic, however.

> Comic book prequel
>
> In late 2005, Dark Horse Comics published a four-issue comic book
>   limited series tying in with the movie. The storyline serves as a
>   prequel to the film and is a mixture of Chung's original TV series
>   designs and characters, combined with the setting and story elements
>   of the film.

Comment: Where they black/white?

Comment: Hey Guru, haha, nah it's not Aeon Flux, but I didn't realize they made a comic book prequel. cool!